# Are the $\Gamma(N)$ the only normal congruence subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

The answer to the original question is no, see JSE's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/60196)!

Are the $\Gamma(N)$ the only normal congruence subgroups of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with no finite subgroups (elliptic elements)? What about the normal subgroups of $\Gamma(4)$, which does not contain torsion elements? Here, $\gamma \in \Gamma(N)$, if $\gamma \cong 1 \mod N$.

$\newcommand\o{\mathfrak o}$I state the question in the local picture for general $G$:
Let $\o$ be a local ring and $G \subset GL(n)$ a group. Then it makes sense to speak about $G( p^r)$, which consists of matrices which are congruent to $1$ modulo $p^r$, where $p$ is the maximal ideal in $\o$. From $\o \rightarrow \o/p^r$, we get an exact sequence
$$ G(p^r) \rightarrow G(\o) \rightarrow G( \o / p^r).$$
Is it surjective? I guess the $G(p^r)$ form a basis of neighborhoods for $1$ and are normal open compact subgroups. Under which conditions are these all normal subgroups in $G(\o)$ with no finite subgroups?

Comment: You need your local ring to be compact in the $p$-adic topology to say that the congruence subgroups are compact.  This is not true for local rings in general, but it is true for complete dvrs.

Comment: I edited to link to JSE's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/60196) while this was on the front page, and on the way thought that it might be acceptable to change $o$ for a local ring to the more visually distinct $\mathfrak o$.  I hope that that was OK.  If not, then I apologise, and please feel free to change back, which you can do all at once just by changing `\newcommand\o{\mathfrak o}` to `\newcommand\o{o}`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Almost but not quite.  A congruence subgroup has to contain some $\Gamma(N)$.  So if it is normal its image in $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})/\Gamma(N)$ is a normal subgroup of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$.  That group is almost simple but not quite.  A proper normal subgroup need not be trivial; it could be $\pm1$ for instance.  Or if $N$ is very small you have a few more choices; for instance, the commutator subgroup of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is a finite-index congruence subgroup of (if I recall correctly) index $12$, containing $\Gamma(6)$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant of course $PSL$ instead of $SL$. What for subgroup of $\Gamma(4)$ instead of $\Gamma(1)$? Do the elipptic elements/finite subgroups give the trouble?

Comment: Please forgive me that I changed the questions accordingly....

Comment: Gamma(4) will have new normal subgroups; Gamma(4)/Gamma(8) is (Z/2Z)^3 so you have a whole bunch of normal subgroups in between those two.

Answer (score 6):

(i) Normal congruence subgroups of PSL(2, Z) have been classified by D. L. McQuillan, in [Classification of Normal Congruence Subgroups of the Modular Group](https://doi.org/10.2307/2373006), Amer. J. Math. 87 (1965), 285–296.
(ii) The only torsion normal subgroups of PSL(2, Z) are the powers subgroups P_n= < x^n : x\in PSL(2,Z)>, where n = 2 or 3.

One may now list all normal congruence subgroups of level N.